# Scicos Code generation for rt_preempt system

Tags: real-time, scilab

Due to http://hart.sourceforge.net/, code generation should work for rt_preempt kernels, when using scilab 5.3.2 and hart toolsbox.
I installed both on ubuntu 12.04 LTS sucessfully, but I'm kind of lost with the code generation. I use one of the hart toolbox examples (realtime_demo), and try to compile and generate code. 
First off all: Are these samples supposed to work with rt_preempt or only with RTAI? what code generation commands do I have to use for rt_preempt kernels?

If anybody managed code generation for rt_preempt kernels, I would aapreciate every hint I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code generation for rt_preempt is automatically enabled, if the hart-toolbox did not detect RTAI during installation. Thus, if you don't have RTAI, by compiling your schematic you should get code that runs using rt_preemption (if this is also not available, then your code will run as a normal Linux process). However at the moment there is no way to get data in or out of the real-time process, as the RTAI scopes, meters can not be used. To overcome this communication issue and also other limitations of Xcos concerning the implementation of real-time systems, you could also have a look at OpenRTDynamics as an alternative.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I already started using ORTD some weeks ago, and it works fine. so the tip was good!